# How can we use Python to load files into Azure Blob Storage or Azure Data Lake Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am relatively new to Azure. I am trying to figure out how to use Python to load files into an Azure storage account, such as Data Lake or Blob Storage. I read the info from the following two URLs, and I am stuck about how to proceed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python

Maybe I missed something from those resource, or they are not right for what I am trying to do. I just want to get a simple example working so I can start to understand the process better.  I would like to do either of the following.

1. copy a file from my desktop to Azure Blob Storage or Data Lake Storage
2. download a file from a URL and save it to Azure Blob Storage or Data Lake Storage

I want to run Python from Azure, so I want the code to run in a 'Runbook'. How can I do either item 1 or 2, as described above, or ideally both 1 and 2?

Comment: Have you seen the samples here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-samples-python?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#blob-samples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the **azure_storage_blob** python package in your automation account

Then, you can use the python code below to upload file to azure blob storage from a URL:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
connect_str = "StorageAccountConnectString"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
destination_blob = blob_service_client.get_blob_client("ContainerName","BlobName")
destination_blob.start_copy_from_url("URL")
```